# How would human society change if everyone had superpowered flatulence?

Tags: culture, social-norms

I would appreciate serious answers for this.  The emissions in question are strong enough to let someone hover for a few seconds, and minor property damage has been recorded.  They are extremely malodorous, although almost everyone's used to the smell.  Assume social change will happen.

Comment: Welcome to World building! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. The problem with your question is that there are far too many aspects to society to answer your question in this format. Please try to narrow it down to the aspect you are interested in the most. Have fun!

Comment: Your question is currently on hold to give you a chance to edit the question without people answering, which could lead to you invalidating answers with edits. By editing your question will automatically go into a reopen edit queue.

Comment: #ThePunchlineIs "They discovered fire..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would stimulate technological research and development into creating blast-proof trousers and more powerful deordorants.

There will be changes in social behaviour. People will place items, for example, of furniture and other forms of minor property in locations to avoid them being damaged by overpowered eructations. As a matter of etiquette people will position their bodies, relative to furniture and other items of minor property, just in case, there is an inadvertent rear-end explosion.

Gas masks might become fashion items along with nose-lugs and ear protectors.

Synchronized emissions might be used as a military tactic, but undoubtedly this will be banned by a Geneva Treaty. Al the world's nations will definitely sign up as Victory gained via Field Artillery Flatulence would be too dishonourable.

Answer (score 2):

Without any further data, I'd have to say "not much."

There's a lot of bodily functions we simply ignore, which to an alien species may be beyond the pale.  Our propensity to shove formerly living life forms into our face could be considered barbaric.  If the temperature gets even a little too high, we start urinating out of every pore of our body.  But because these things are normal for us, we don't really reflect on it too hard.

"Hover farts" would simply be another one of those things;  either they'd be impolite or simply ignored, like somebody who's sweaty fresh from some sweaty activity.

Now, if the farts caused lightning or were exceptionally stinky, maybe they'd have a big impact.  But hovering for a "split second" isn't very useful.  It's not a super power, it's just an odd body function, and in your universe, EVERYONE has it.  It's not caused by Taco Bell or a genetic mutation;  it's one of those weird things that the humans in your universe wouldn't consider weird.

Comment: Here's the further data you requested.  Yes, they do qualify as exceptionally stinky, and they're equally forceful, to the point where minor to moderate property damage has been recorded.  Also, it's only really been in effect for around the last century or so.  Sorry that I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: @AnonY.Mous, putting further data in a comment to an answer which can be deleted is not a good idea to improve the quality of your question. Use the edit button below your question to add other info to your question.